# Is there a way to spread a paragraph over all of a text frame's columns in InDesign?

Tags: adobe-indesign, page-layout, typesetting, paragraph-styles, formatting

I'm laying out a text with lists and headings between them. I used the 'Text frame options' to split a page-wide text frame into two columns. Now, it so happens that one of my main headings is too wide to fit in a single column. I think line breaking the column is very ugly, so I'd prefer it if I could instruct this single line (or paragraph) to ignore the column separation and go all the way across the entire text frame. Not dissimilar from what two merged cells in a table would look like.

For now, I split my text into three separate frames on that page, with one of them containing the heading not split into any columns. This works, but feels like a huge hack and is very impractical in any case the text needs to reflow.

Is it possible to do this in any 'official', proper way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The proper way is to edit the paragraph style for headings and in the `Span Columns` tab, choose `Span All`. You also get options to limit the span to 2, 3 or more columns.

[image]

Comment: Great, thanks! I knew this option existed, but couldn't remember for the life of me what it was called or where to find it.

Comment: For one-offs, that you don't want to apply a style to directly, the Span/Split options should be at the [far right of the control bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kUaGs.png) with the text tool active, @Vincent -- same thing, merely local and no style.

Comment: I also found the option in the Paragraph palette's options, and that's the (local) method I ended up using. Thanks, both!